# What is the name of a photographic effect where there are subtle shadows in corners?

Tags: terminology, photography

If you take pictures and the aperture settings are not ideal, you will see a light shadow in the corners.

Example:

[image: example]

This effect is a sign of bad quality, but is also often used as a design element in movies, pictures and so on - how is it called?

I want to use it, but I have no clue how it's called.

Comment: Not always a sign of bad quality. My lens filters often create this effect due to them just being attached to my camera. Sometimes it just happens!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is called [**Vignetting**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vignetting), which, as you described:

> […] is a reduction of an image's brightness or saturation at the periphery compared to the image center.

It can appear as

- Mechanical (filters used in a shoot, improper lens hood, etc)
- Optical (lens)
- Natural (illumination falloff)
- Pixel (digital sensor's alignment to the scene)
- Photographic film (the film's properties)

Nowadays it can be easily done in post-processing.